# How to give scroll bar to an WPF treeview

Tags: wpf, vb.net, treeview

I have used the

```
<ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">
    <TreeView ...>
    </TreeView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

but not properly working I want a new one

Answer (score 3):

`TreeView` manages its own scroll viewer. You'll want to set either `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` or `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisiblity` to `Visible` *on the tree view itself* to force the respective scrollbars to display.

```
<TreeView
  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, make sure your TreeView doesn't live inside a control that will extend vertically forever - a common mistake is this:

```
<StackPanel>
   <... />
      <TreeView>
```

In this example, the TreeView will grow longer and longer without scrolling, because the StackPanel has infinite height.

Comment: This is the exact situation I encountered. Thanks for the tip.